# Add content of showModalDialog() to the clipboard Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, modal-dialog, clipboard

I have formatted data being added to a Modal Dialog when I click a button

I want to the content of the `showModalDialog()` to be automatically added to the clipboard when I click the button as well

The modal is being generated with the below code, and `temp` is the output I want added to the clipboard

```
//Output to Html
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
              .createHtmlOutput(temp)
              .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
              .setWidth(600)
              .setHeight(500);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Filter OptionList Maker');
```

Edit; Ok, I guess maybe the `Modal Dialog` might be beside-the-point and the proper question might be how to add the formatted string `temp` to the clipboard

Here is an example of what I mean by formatted string

```
filter {
  target: element;
  as: dropdown;
  padding: 5;
  summary: "Network Practice";
  default: show-all;
  multiple: true;

  option {
   label: "< 1 year";
   selector: element["NETWORK PRACTICE"="< 1 year"];
  }
  option {
   label: "1-3 years";
   selector: element["NETWORK PRACTICE"="1-3 years"];
  }
  option {
   label: "3-10 years";
   selector: element["NETWORK PRACTICE"="3-10 years"];
  }
  option {
   label: "> 10 years";
   selector: element["NETWORK PRACTICE"=">10 years"];
  }
 }
```

I have searched on how to do this but I have found no solution

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `textarea` in html and copy data in it to clipboard using a button inside html.

### Snippet:

#### copy.html:

```html
<textarea id="copy"><?=temp?></textarea>
<button>Copy</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let t = document.getElementById('copy');
  let copy = () => {
    t.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  };
  copy();//try copying without user click 
  let bt = document.querySelector('button');
  bt.addEventListener('click', copy);
</script>
```

#### code.gs

```
//Output to Html
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('copy');
template.temp = temp;
var htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Filter OptionList Maker');
```

### To Read:

- [Interact with clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)
- [HTML Template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: document.execCommand is deprecated, and the recommended replacement, navigator.clipboard.writeText, gives a security error in this context.  Not sure if you can properly grant the required iframe permissions, since they seem to be set in stone: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions

Comment: @Kev If I'm not mistaken, `execCommand('copy')` still works. If you want the new permissions on the iframe, The easiest way is to  propose a feature request to Google on the issuetracker and asking a question here with the tracker link to increase stars on the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: It does still work, you're right, sorry for not highlighting that fact.  Thanks for the link.  :)