# Accessing Clipboard API in Apps Script html dialog

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, clipboard

I have a Google Spreadsheet file that displays a custom dialog using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ShowModalDialog(...)`.

There is a script in this dialog box that saves some user values to the clipboard
`navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)`

This construct worked great until today. Now when I try to access the clipboard, I get an error

> "NotAllowedError: Disabled in this document by Feature Policy."

I don't know how it was before, but now in the iframe container of the dialog box there is no permission for clipboard. Chrome and Firefox have the same result

```html
<iframe id="sandboxFrame" allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; speaker *; usb *; vibrate *; vr *" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="https://n-u5k3jk3vgvz7z7zd77h6oqbtfn7mio6cjscfeoi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel">
</iframe>
```

Is there any way to set permission for [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) in Apps Script html dialogs?

Comment: This should be modified by Google. Consider creating a issue in the issuetracker and link the issue you created here for wider audience. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details. Also [edit] your question to show browser variances. Does Firefox or other browsers show the same behavior?

Comment: I use this is a dialog  box and a web app `var textbox=document.getElementById(id);
      textbox.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');`

Comment: If you are in an iframe with no clipboard allowed execCommand with copy / cut / paste options don't work

Comment: Create  a issue. That's the only way.

Comment: As @TheMaster said. Please, open an issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) and describe in detail the situation you are having

Comment: Where is reported issue URL?

Comment: This one https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760406 ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681314/add-content-of-showmodaldialog-to-the-clipboard-google-script