# Script to copy only the result of a cell with embedded formula

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, clipboard

```
function copyCell() {
  var thisBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var thisSheet = thisBook.getSheetByName('Filt_N');
  thisSheet.getRange(1, 1).getvalue();
}
```

I want to make a button that will copy the value of a single cell without pasting anywhere. I do not know how to continue this script.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do this copied  content? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57682572/

Comment: just to copy the value to window clipboard. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. See  the link above. But you would need 2 button clicks. One to open the modal dialog and  another to copy to clipboard.